# How to run kubernetes on top of docker swarm?

Tags: kubernetes

I want docker swarm cluster that managed by kubernetes. I want to build cloud provider and I want to have Docker swarm as a service And I want to o that by kubernetes?
What should I do? Is it possible to do that?

I know what is docker swarm and what is kubernetes and they do one thing but is it possible to to run docker swarm by kubernetes?

Comment: They both kind of do the same thing; it doesn't really make sense to try to use both at the same time (or one on top of the other).  Can you give an example of the sort of use case you're trying to accommodate?  Do you have some actual source code that's relevant to the problem?

Comment: I know they both kind of same thing. I change my question how can run kubernetes on top of kubernetes? they both is a same thing.